# Doing multiple mapreduce jobs in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am currently writing codes that run on hadoop streaming in Python. However, I am trying to do one mapping and two reducing jobs.

When I try to run the code using the following command, only one reducer - the first one - is working.

I am using this command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=user -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3276m -Dmapred.output.compress=false -file mapper.py -file reducer_tf_hcuot.py -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer_tf_hcuot.py -input text -output o_text
```

Can you please tell me how to work on it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It looks like you didn't actually include the command or the code in your question.

Comment: and please, clarify what you mean by "one mapping and two reducing jobs"

Comment: I want to run one mapper, and then two reducers.

Comment: From my experience you may have to run mapper, reducer, identity mapper and then your second reducer, however I haven't used hadoop in a year or two so this may be out of date. Edit: I've used yelp's Mrjob in the past to handle some of the flows like this (tying together multiple jobs). May be worth a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hadoop streaming, you can only run 1 map and 1 reduce job at a time (at present).

You can essentially run 2 mappers (or any number of mappers) in 1 job by piping the output of first map function to the second map function.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR -mapper 'map1.py | map2.py | map3.py' -reducer 'reduce.py' ...
```

However for multiple reducers, as Ned Rockson said, you'll have 2 independent jobs by using identity mapper in the second job

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR -mapper 'map.py' -reducer 'reduce1.py' ...
hadoop jar $HADOOP_JAR -mapper '/bin/cat' -reducer 'reduce2.py' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is want you want:

"hadoop-multiple-streaming extends Hadoop-Streaming which is a utility that comes with the Hadoop distribution.
This utility allows you to not only do Hadoop-Streaming, but also create and run 'multiple' Map/Reduce jobs for 'one' input with any executable or scripts. For example:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-multiple-streaming.jar \  
  -input    myInputDirs \  
  -multiple "outputDir1|mypackage.Mapper1|mypackage.Reducer1" \  
  -multiple "outputDir2|mapper2.sh|reducer2.sh" \  
  -multiple "outputDir3|mapper3.py|reducer3.py" \  
  -multiple "outputDir4|/bin/cat|/bin/wc" \  
  -libjars  "libDir/mypackage.jar" \
  -file     "libDir/mapper2.sh" \  
  -file     "libDir/mapper3.py" \  
  -file     "libDir/reducer2.sh" \  
  -file     "libDir/reducer3.py"
```

This project is the maven project. So you can simply do maven build command for making hadoop-multiple-streaming.jar file. In more detail, 'mvn clean package' command will compile source code and packaging to ${project_home}/target folder."

Took from https://github.com/hyonaldo/hadoop-multiple-streaming.

Answer (score -1):

Do as first said 'map1.py | map2.py | map3.py', this is not work, only map1.py can be executed.

The right thing to do is with [mrjob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/configs-hadoopy-runners.html)(the Python MapReduce library),hope this helps